# Native login with Instagram API

Tags: php, api, authentication, oauth-2.0, instagram

I've been working on an app for IG, and was looking at other websites which use the IG API. I came across [this](http://www.instaliker.net/) website which allows the user to login by entering their username and password directly into the site. It is then able to access the IG API and fetch things like follower count, however without the user authenticating an IG API Client as would normally be required. The app can even perform functions such as liking pictures using your account, which as far as I know also requires you to authenticate an app with elevated privileges.

My question is, how is this app able to login users without using OAUTH which [appears to be the only method of authentication](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They probably use a web automation framework like Selenium to take actions like auto-linking content by actually logging in to the Instagram web site with the accounts credentials and simulating mouse clicks, etc. to get the job done. In other words their "script" just looks like a very active user to Instagram because it's all coming from interactions between a web browser and their site.

They definitely are not using the API. Several reasons you can know this:

1. no OAuth flow to get an access_token
2. they don't appear in the authorized applications section if you log in and manage your profile
3. what they are doing is a violation of the API Terms of Use. See the following under "shall not"

> Use the Instagram APIs to post automated content to Instagram, including likes and comments that were not initiated and entered by an Instagram user.

I'm no lawyer and I have no inside information, however it seems clear enough to me that Instagram does not want this type of "bot" activity.

They claim that they have the timing set up in a way that they go undetected, but I think it's a safe bet that there are algorithms at Instagram trying to detect and prevent this type of activity and if they do, accounts would be at risk of being disabled, etc. I have not inside knowledge here, just speculation.

Comment: `Use the Instagram APIs to...` - Since they're not technically using the API would this still apply?

Comment: I guess not. I tried the site with a throwaway account I use for testing and Instagram already sent me a notice that I needed to change my password because of "suspicious activity". In other words, they detected the bot.

Answer (score 0):

The `Instagram` application that you use from your cellphone uses `HTTP/HTTPS` communication with their application server. The link that you provided on the question uses to simulate those `http` calls to mimic as an `Instagram` application.

You can redirect your cell phone's Internet connection through the proxy(your own proxy server). From your proxy server catch the web requests those are being sent by the `Instagram` application when you are doing login, liking, etc.

It will be easy for you if the requests are through `http` channel. But if its through the `https`, then it will be really difficult to capture those. You can try with `Fidler` or some sort of similar softwares for this.

Answer (score 0):

What I THINK is happening is the following:

They are logging your **PHPSESSID** and using that so you have the ability to like pictures and whatnot. They are doing all of the back-end work directly in index.php.

If you track the requests that are being sent to index.php through the Network tab in Chrome, you will see that "Cookie:***_*** instamacro_advcontent=1; PHPSESSID=" on the index.php file "Headers" tab.

I'm doing the same with my website that uses Vine's API(not public, btw). In a PHP file I created called api.php, I use Vine's API to perform actions. I do not use OAUTH at all. I simply use the users "x-vine-session" cookie.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Your answer is a little hard to understand.

Comment: Basically in a nutshell, they use your "PHPSESSID" to perform actions and bypass that OAUTH step. Click [here](http://davine.co/TV) to see the website I was talking about before that I made, that is basically doing the same thing.